# How to zip specific files and folders in subdirectories using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder structure for example like this

```
- folder1
  - folderA
  - folderB
    - backup
      - folder0
      - file1
      - file2
- folder2
  - folderX
  - folderY
    - backup
      - folder0
      - file1
      - file2
```

I want the files and folders (in this example 'folder0' 'file1' 'file2') that are inside the folders 'backup' in backup.zip and delete the folder 'backup' after it's done.

An example of the result I'm expecting to achieve.

```
- folder1
  - folderA
  - folderB
    backup.zip
- folder2
  - folderX
  - folderY
    backup.zip
```

This is what I have so far.

```
Get-ChildItem '.' -r -Filter backup| ForEach-Object {Compress-Archive $_.FullName "$($_.DirectoryName)/$($_.BaseName)" | Remove-Item template}
```

this creates a backup.zip file in the root directory I'm working in. And has everything including the folder 'backup' which was not required.

Comment: You are asking about powershell, but you are also tagging it with _bash_ and with _batch_. Why? Tag only with the shell you are wanting to discuss.

Comment: sorry for that.. new to this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would get all directories named backup, and iterate through them to compress their contents to a .zip beside the backup directory. Then delete the backup directory.

```
 Get-ChildItem '.' -r -Filter backup -Directory | ForEach-Object { Compress-Archive ($_.FullName+'\*') ($_.FullName+'.zip'); Remove-Item $_.FullName -r;}
```